# Cordova: What is the right location to store recorded Audio files in iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, media, phonegap-build

I am using media plugin to record sounds.

```
var my_media = new Media('test.wav');
my_media.startRecord();
my_media.stopRecord() // after few seconds
my_media.release();
my_media.play();//works fine


// But when I try to Check if test.wav file exist I always get false as status.


//File name of our important data file we didn't ship with the app
var fileName = "test.wav";

function init() {

console.log("Checking for data file.");

//Check for the file. 
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileName, onSuccess, onFail);

}

function onSuccess() {
console.log("Great! This file exists");
 }

function onFail() {
console.log('Sorry! File not Found');
}

// I always get this message: Sorry! File not Found
```

What is right way to do this? After recording I want user to be able to see list of available recorded sounds and user should be able to play it. For that I need to check if file exists or not.
So how should we implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display list of recorded files as:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(YOUR_PATH, {
        create: true
    }, function(directory) {
        root_path = fileSystem.root.toURL();
        var directoryReader = directory.createReader();
        directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                //Get file URL as: entries[i].toURL()); & display using creating dynamic tag.
            }
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error.code);
        });

    });
}, function(error) {
    alert("can't even get the file system: " + error.code);
});
```

Comment: I tried to run your code but I am getting this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','

Comment: Have you replace "YOUR_PATH" with your actual path where the recording exists ? And make sure, root_path is not null.

Comment: Yes I replaced "Your_PATH" with actual path but it is still showing syntaxError

Comment: Install two plugins 1) cordova-plugin-file 2) cordova-plugin-file-transfer.

Comment: Those plugins are already installed. This is not issue of plugin. This is syntax issue.

Comment: Then please specify the line where you got SyntaxError.

Comment: You gave me answer with syntax answer any editor can tell you that this syntax has error.

Comment: still error. you can also check it online http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Comment: Also, you can check on the same link. It is WARNING, not error.

Comment: What would I write in place of YOUR_PATH ? 
I have no specific path as you can see in my question above. I just recorded sound with no path. I just mentioned name of recording.
So I just want to show list of all recorded sounds.

Comment: test.wav you need to store in internal storage, and that path can be your YOUR_PATH. In my case, I have stored audio files to test folder. So my YOUR_PATH is test.